# How to generate the JSON path for every leaf node in JSON object?

Tags: javascript, php, json, regex

I have a complex JSON object with several nested node and I need to extract JSON path of every leaf node in JSON. The depth of the JSON object is unknown at the run time.

The path should have all the node from root to the parent of the leaf node (the value) in the JSON. All the node in the jsonpath should be separated by . (period).

Any suggestion about how to do this in Javascript or PHP?

Comment: yes: write a recursive function to walk through that object.

Comment: I am also interested in knowing if this is already solved in some existing open source libraries/packages/modules in php or javascript.

Comment: just google it! I found that one f.e.:http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used JSONPath library for PHP from here - https://github.com/Galbar/JsonPath-PHP